# Is it possible to request multiple same-level deep nodes by single query in Firebase

Tags: database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Consider the below database structure. Can I request all the movies (movie1, movie2, ..etc) in a single query? if so, how?

```
"by_genre"
      "comedy"
          "by_lead"
              "Jack Nicholson"
                  "movie1"
              "Jim Carrey"
                  "movie3"
      "Horror"
          "by_lead"
              "Jack Nicholson"
                  "movie2"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to the question is no, you cannot query for all of the movies without reading in all of the by_genre child nodes and iterating over them.

But...

Changing your structure would be one option

```
all_movies
   movie_id_0
     title: "The Shining"
     year: "1980"
     genre: "Horror"
     lead: "Jack Nicholson"
   movie_id_1
     title: "One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest"
     year: "1975"
     genre: "Comedy"
     lead: "Jack Nicholson"
   movei_id_2
     title: "Liar Liar"
     year: "1997"
     genre: "Comedy"
     lead: "Jim Carrey"
```

This structure is flexible as you can query all movies by year, genre or lead or just all movies which satisfies the question.

You could have additional access to the data by adding another node such as

```
genre
  comedy
   movie_id_1: true
   movie_id_2: true
  horror
   movie_id_0: true
```

There may be other requirements and if so, we can update the answer.